# Override the project-default.yml values dynamically?

Tags: yaml, cdi, thorntail

I have a **thorntail** project and with the following **project-default.yml** file below:

```
simulation:
   vehicle:
      speed: 1
```

Is there any way that I can **override/change/update** the values of **project-default.yml** dynamically?

Comment: How is this explicitly cdi related? What problem does cdi create? Or what do you want it to do? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use system properties (see https://docs.thorntail.io/2.6.0.Final/#application-configuration-using-system-properties_thorntail) or environment variables (see https://docs.thorntail.io/2.6.0.Final/#configuring-a-thorntail-application-using-environment-variables_thorntail).

In your case, you can e.g. run `java -Dsimulation.vehicle.speed=42 -jar my-app-thorntail.jar` to change that configuration property to `42`.